# Intersection number of the tangent at the Inflexion point of $y=x^3$

Tags: algebraic-curves

We know that the intersection number of this curve $f=y-x^3$ and its tangent at the origin is $3$.

I'm trying to use this method described in the Fulton's book:

[image]

[image]

Following this definition we have the intersection number equals to $1$, because $m=1$ and $f_1=y$.

Am I missing something?

thanks

Comment: The point $(0,0)$ in the curve is not a singular point (double, triple, …), because the form at the origin is just $Y$, which has degree $1$. The tangent at this point has an intersection number of $3$, because it's a flex.

Comment: @egreg is it possible a point has an intersection number 3 with the tangent line and having only one tangent with multiplicity 1 at this point in the same time?

Comment: Yes, at flexes.

Answer (score 3):

You're confusing the concepts. Fulton is talking about singular points (double, triple, and so on). If you write the polynomial you have in the stated form, you get
$$
F=Y-X^3=F_3(X,Y)+F_2(X,Y)+F_1(X,Y)
$$
where
$$
F_1(X,Y)=Y,\quad
F_2(X,Y)=0,\quad
F_3(X,Y)=-X^3
$$
which means that $(0,0)$ is a simple point. The tangent is indeed the line $Y=0$. When you compute the intersections, you solve
$$
\begin{cases}
Y-X^3=0\\
Y=0
\end{cases}
$$
which gives $X^3=0$, so you conclude that the tangent and the curve have intersection number $3$ at the origin.

A different case is that of the *Folium Cartesii*,
$$
F(X,Y)=X^3+X^2-Y^2
$$
where, with notation as before,
$$
F_1(X,Y)=0,\quad
F_2(X,Y)=X^2-Y^2,\quad
F_3(X,Y)=X^3
$$
Then the origin is a double point and the tangents are given by $X^2-Y^2=0$, that is, they are $X=Y$ and $X=-Y$. A double point with simple tangents.

Comment: I was confusing, thank you very much for your help